# How capture full screen shot for Local website project?

Tags: html

I have lot of website (css3 and html5). I want to put that as a portfolio page. But System capture almost half of website only.

I browsed for that. Some website capture full screen short,.. But they need url in online.

(http://www.capturefullpage.com/)

But my website projects are in my computer only. I am not uploading that.

Is Any Idea to get full screen Shot website which is in offline.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With it being Summer 2014 as I am writing this, the accepted answer does not seem up to date anymore, or at least does not work for me. See my answer below for a solution that works for me. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this Chrome Plugin <s>[WebpageScreenshot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ckibcdccnfeookdmbahgiakhnjcddpki).</s> 
[Fireshot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/take-webpage-screenshots/mcbpblocgmgfnpjjppndjkmgjaogfceg?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)
It allows you to take a screenshot of the complete page or just the visible area with an option to auto save

Update-

[Fireshot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fireshot/?src=userprofile) for firefox provides you similar functionality for firefox.
As jdh pointed out if you are using the latest version of chrome you can always print your screen to pdf by going to the print menu and selecting `Print to PDF` as destination.

Comment: No one extension not working in local.

Comment: @Sagotharan i guess then you will have to stick to print to pdf

Answer (score 4):

The following solution has solved this problem for me:

1. Download and install **Full Page Screen Capture** from 
   https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-page-screen-capture/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl
2. After the installation is finished, go to "Tools\Extensions"
3. Look for "Full Page Screen Capture" and tick the box **"Allow access to file URLs"**

Now you can capture images from local/file URLs :)

Answer (score 0):

Print to a PDF file. Odds are your PC has a PDF print driver already installed. This is nicer to present if its more than one screen long, giving your viewer the ability to page thru the results.

Answer (score 0):

At last, I found a suitable software. [WebPage Thumbnailer](http://www.webpagethumbnailer.com/) is very easy to use and does not cost much.

Answer (score 0):

You can [Snagit](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html)!!

Answer (score 0):

Use [EverNote](https://www.evernote.com) to Capture full page screenshot, record audio, create todo list and organise for free.

Comment: Sorry, but if it wasn't for your long history on Stack Exchange, I would have thought this was spam.  This is an ancient question looking to do one thing: get a full screen shot of a website.  There are a lot of dedicated utilities that do that well and conveniently, and there are many existing answers with applicable ones.  Why would you recommend a complicated notetaking app that happens to include taking screenshots?  And what benefit here are any of the other things it can do?  Do you really think this contributes a good solution to the existing answers?

Comment: Thanks for considering me as Human :-) I ran into similar situation and had a look at the answers, tried some of them and ended up using EverNote. Reason for choosing EverNote was it's free, popular, and over to all stores Html rather than just an image, it allows me to search the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of Firefox have reasonable screenshot functionality built in. Try right-clicking on an 'empty' area of the page and then select 'Take Screenshot'. The remaining steps are pretty self-explanatory. Mozilla's web page on this: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/take-screenshots-firefox .